# How do I add a data attribute to my Rails modal window link?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, modal-dialog, custom-data-attribute

I’m using Rails 4.2.3 with the jquery-modal-rails gem.  This is so that I can easily spawn modal windows out of a DIV on my page.  I’m trying to create a link to activate the modal window, and I want this link to have a “data-id” attribute so that I can run some JS prior to the modal window opening.  So I tried

```
<%= link_to_modal "Edit", "#add_form", :class=>'edit_link', :data-id=>my_object_time.my_object.id %>
```

but I get the error

```
undefined local variable or method `id' for #<#<Class:0x007fc692bc9ef8>:0x007fc69b0079b8>
```

It is complaining about the line above (if I remove the “-id” part the link renders, but then I don’t have a data-id attribute).

Comment: are you sure your ```my_object``` is what you expect it to be? cause it seems like it's not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change to this:

```
<%= link_to_modal "Edit", "#add_form", :class=>'edit_link', "data-id" =>my_object_time.my_object.id %>
```

That is the syntax, you can not define something like:

```
{:data-id => my_object_time.my_object.id}
```

Because when you use `:data-id`, ruby will understand like:

`:data` - (minus) `id`, so `-` is undefined for symbol, and `id` also is undefined!

But this will work fine:

```
{"data-id" => my_object_time.my_object.id}
```

It is a normal string, in you case, let's use string